# callback not occuring onPress

Tags: react-native

Everything seems okay as I look, but the callback is not triggering onPress, need help with another pair of eyes to identify where the problem is.

```
class RandomNumber extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        number: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    };

    handlePress = () => {
        console.log(this.props.number);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
                <Text style={styles.random}>{this.props.number}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here. Can you put a `console.log` inside the render function, and confirm that you are able to read logs correctly?

Comment: oh I'm seeing the logs within the terminal (WebStorm) not chrome debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handlePress` syntax is wrong, since you are trying to replace the original Event Handler triggered with the *onPress* event.

This is the right syntax (if you want to refer to it into render method like what have you done):

```js
    handlePress = () => event => {
        console.log(this.props.number);
    };
```

It's like you are wrapping the original event handler with this new one.

This is a very powerful pattern, since with this you are able to avoid anonymous arrow functions into *render()*

You can read more about this lovely pattern here: https://medium.com/silesis/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb

Comment: it makes sense but i think there's something else too, see the screenshot in my question please.

Comment: Is it still not working? Have you enabled the "Debug JS Remotely" option? (shake android real device or CMD+D if you are using iOS simulator)